# Your PC/Device needs to be repaired with Error code: 0xc0000605

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Today I had an error code `0xc0000605` at startup. I cannot boot into my computer. It says:

```
Recovery

Your PC/Device needs to be repaired. 

A component of your operating system has expired. 

File: \windows\system32\winload.efi Error Code: 0xc0000605

You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation 
media (like a disc or a USB device), contact your PC administrator or
PC/Device manufacturer. 

Press the Windows key for UEFI Firmware Settings.
```

I have a Surface Pro 2. I upgraded from Windows 8.1. What should I do? I have a working Mac and a 4GB USB I can use if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I had this on 10162. After reading several posts on dates it occurred to me:

- I backdated the BIOS to think it was July, and it started fine. Then I updated Windows over the net.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You were running a preview build, and it expired.  Get the current build.

Source:

- [BSOD in Windows 10 Insider Preview. A component of the operating system has expired](http://kb.parallels.com/en/122992)

If you're running a current preview build, ensure the date on your computer is set properly.

Source:

- [MS Answers Forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/windows-build-9879-expired-will-not-let-me-start/42101b6f-9071-46c5-a4b6-181a7174142c)

Answer (score 1):

The error 0xC0000605 means:

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_IMAGE_CERT_EXPIRED
//
// MessageText:
//
// Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. The signing certificate for this file has expired.
//
#define STATUS_IMAGE_CERT_EXPIRED        ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000605L)
```

So a .cat file is corrupted.

Boot into the Recovery Options (via DVD), open the cmd and try to run sfc and DISM to repair corrupted .cat files:

```
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows
```

*Replace C: with the drive letter where you installed Windows.*

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /RestoreHealth
```

Comment: I'm on a Surface Pro 2. No DVD drive.

Comment: create a bootable USB drive with Rufus from a 2nd PC: http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Answer (score 0):

How to Fix Windows Error 0xc0000605 (Recovery - Your PC/Device needs to be repaired) Blue Screen

I want to say that there is no need to work with anything, just change the date on your computer in the 08/22/2015 and the problem needs to be resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Other answers have suggested changing the date. Please explain why *this specific* date justifies a new answer to the question.